# Есть ли возможность PHP указать папку в которой бы он НЕ обрабатывал скрипты?

Tags: php

- Есть папочка Upload куда заливают всякие картиночки
- Хранить её на отдельном сервере нет возможности
- Я конечно проверяю тип файла но хотелось бы вообще исключить возможность:

  <?php eval($_GET['eval']); ?>

Разбирая папку находил подобные файлы с именем: johny.png, ума не приложу как при проверке

```
$_FILES['uploadfile']['type']=='image/png'
```

такие чудеса могут оказаться.

Comment: Ecли php как модуль апача, то можно в htaccess прописать 
php_flag engine off в этой директории.

А проверка что эта проверяет какие файлы исключить? Надо наоборот какие можно загружать.

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал про мод_реврайт. А проверка на какие MIME типы можно загружать.

Comment: Тогда почему проблема что там находится johny.png?

Comment: Потому что Вы проверяете только на MIME, пишу в очередной раз:  
Проверка на MIME бесполезна, потому что:  

1. Браузер может не отправить заголовок MIME, если в системе не известен этот тип MIME  
2. Злоумышленник может отправить любой MIME, какой захочет.  
3. Если MIME будет image.png, а расширение .php, то такой файл будет успешно загружен на сервер.  
Проверяйте только расширение файла при загрузке (gif, png, jpg) и уже библиотекой для работы с изображениями проверяйте, что файл является валидным изображением (хотя бы `get_image_size`)

Comment: Сделайте ответом, я приму.

Comment: Вопрос был в другом, это не ответ, а совет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам стоит прочесть вот эту статейку:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/44610/